# Passing same value of method to multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

In my window application I have orderNumber that need to be passed to another form. This order number is generated by the code which I will put below. I am trying to pass only 1 identical order number to two locations but unfortunately, two different order number passed to both location. How can I make that only one order number is passed to both location.

**Code that generates the order number:**

```
public string orderNumber()
        {
           string ord = "ORD" + get_next_id() + DateTime.Now.Year;
           return ord;

       }

 public int get_next_id()
        {
            OleDbConnection objConnection = null;
            OleDbCommand objCmd = null;
            String sql;
            int res;

            // Create and open the connection object
            objConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);

            objConnection.Open();
            sql = "SELECT IIF(MAX(Customer.NumGenerate) IS NULL,100,MAX(Customer.NumGenerate)) as v_max FROM Customer;";
            objCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, objConnection);
            res = (int)objCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            ++res;
            objConnection.Close();
            return res;
        }
```

In the first form the following insert method uses the order number:

```
private void SaveAllListItems()
        {
            string listItems = string.Empty;
            foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
            {

                listItems += listBoxItem.ToString();

                if (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBoxItem) < listBox1.Items.Count - 1)
                {
                    listItems += ", ";
                }
            }

            InsertUser(maskedTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, maskedTextBox2.Text, maskedTextBox3.Text, maskedTextBox4.Text, maskedTextBox5.Text,
                       maskedTextBox6.Text, maskedTextBox7.Text, maskedTextBox8.Text, maskedTextBox9.Text, listItems, DateTime.Now, maskedTextBox10.Text, orderNumber(), get_next_id());

;
        }
```

In second form I want to use the same order number which is being used to insert user. right now I have the following code which is not working as form1 has different order number and form 2 has different.

```
 private void FindOrder()
        {


            Form1 m = new Form1();
            string number = m.orderNumber();
          //  string number = "ORD1012013";

            string InvSql = "SELECT  (Customer.[Title] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Customer's Name]) as CustomerName, Customer.[Customer's Ebayname], Customer.[Email Address], Customer.[Phone Number], (Customer.[Address 1] + SPACE(2)  +Customer.[Address 2] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[City] + SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Post Code]+  SPACE(2)  + Customer.[Country]) as Address, Customer.[Item Purchased], Customer.[Purchased Date], Customer.[Total Price], Customer.[OrderNumber] FROM Customer WHERE Customer.[OrderNumber]= '" + number + "'";

            OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            OleDbCommand cmdOrder = new OleDbCommand(InvSql, cnn);
            cnn.Open();

            OleDbDataReader rdrOrder = cmdOrder.ExecuteReader();


            rdrOrder.Read();
            custName.Text = rdrOrder["CustomerName"].ToString();
            ebayName.Text = rdrOrder["Customer's Ebayname"].ToString();
            email.Text = rdrOrder["Email Address"].ToString();
            phone.Text = rdrOrder["Phone Number"].ToString();
            address.Text = rdrOrder["Address"].ToString();
            item.Text = rdrOrder["Item Purchased"].ToString();
            date.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(rdrOrder["Purchased Date"]));
            price.Text = rdrOrder["Total Price"].ToString();
            order.Text = rdrOrder["OrderNumber"].ToString();


            rdrOrder.Close();
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

How can I pass same order number to both location?

Comment: why not use a public property on your second form and set the value on form2 constructor.

Comment: can u just give me an example what are you trying to say>

Answer (score 0):

Data can be passed between forms in different ways.

Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms) on how to do that.The Constructor and Property approach is easier to implement.

You dont seem to be saving the orderid on the form1 class

Declare a variable for the OrderID on Form1 class

```
string OrderId;
```

Modify your exisiting Method

```
public string orderNumber()
{
  OrderId = "ORD" + OrderId + DateTime.Now.Year;      
}
```

And then follow the Constructor Approach to pass over the value to PrintForm

Again declare a variable for orderID inside the PrintForm class

```
string OrderId;
```

Change your PrintForm Constructor to this

```
public PrintForm(string value)
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  OrderId=value;
}
```

on Form1 Button click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PrintForm frm=new PrintForm(OrderId);
    PrintForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: if I pass the value with constructor method, it will still have two order number as the orderNumber method will be called which will produce different order number. I Need to save it somewhere before I pass to both location so that both location will have same number.

Comment: i didnt get you.i thought you were having problem with passing values.can you reprhase your problem statement.Is the order number method called again on the second form ?

Comment: @Codelgnoto  Sorry I thought I was clear with the question. Anyway in my windows form there are two form: Form1 and PrintForm. In Form1 user enter information and clicks add entry button which saves the entered information in the database with the order number generated by public string OrderNumber() method. Now I want to pass the same order number value to the PrintForm. If I call Form1.OrderNumber from PrintForm, it will have different order number..

Comment: @Codelgnoto it showing orderId null at PrintForm frm=new PrintForm(OrderId);

Comment: please make sure you are passing the value over the constructor.

Comment: when I put break point in string OrderId in the Form1 I can see its value but by the time code reach OrderId in Form2 it becomes null...Not sure why value is being lost..

Answer (score 0):

Create a container `class` with a `static` property in the same `namespace`:

```
class clsDummy
 {
  internal static string ptyValue { get; set; }
 }
```

you can assign this property where you are getting order id:

```
public string orderNumber()
 {
   string ord = "ORD" + get_next_id() + DateTime.Now.Year;
   clsDummy.ptyValue =ord ;
   return ord;
 }
```

after that where ever you want to access just check value inside : `clsDummy.ptyValue`